# RSelenium with Docker Fails in RScript but works in RStudio

Tags: r, selenium, rscript

I am trying to use the `selenium/standalone-chrome` Docker image, RSelenium, and an `RScript` to setup some automated web-scraping via my mac's command line. While the code below *will* work in `RStudio`, it won't work when I try to run it via `RScript`...I have tried to google and github my way to a solution, but haven't had any luck...the error I see is:

`Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Empty reply from server`

I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this issue, and what they did to resolve it? If it helps, I do intend to run this on either Ubuntu/Amazon linux one day, but I'd like to test and develop on my Mac at the moment.

#### Script Code

```
library(RSelenium)

# Kill any docker containers and start up a docker container with selenium & chrome
system('docker kill $(docker ps -q)')
Sys.sleep(2)
system('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
Sys.sleep(2)
system('docker container ls')

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")

# Open the remote Driver
remDr$open()
# Go to Google
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")

# Screenshot for proof
remDr$screenshot(display=TRUE, useViewer = TRUE)
```

#### Works in RStuido:

[image]

#### Fails in RScript:

[image]

As always, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
-nate